# Type mismatch between SwiftUI textFieldStyle modifiers RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle and PlainTextFieldStyle

Tags: swiftui, textfield, textfieldstyle

I'm attempting to change the `.textFieldStyle` modifier for a `TextField` based upon whether my `View` is editing. I declare `var isEditing: Bool`, set this in the parent `View` and check against this in the `body`. My code:

```
TextField("Type a Name", text: $name) {
    myManagedObjectObserved.attribute = name
}
.textFieldStyle(isEditing ? RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle() : PlainTextFieldStyle())
```

The compiler complains with the following build time error...

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types
> 'RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle' and 'PlainTextFieldStyle'

Don't understand why? Is anyone able to explain please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different types, so swift type checking reports error.

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12)

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if isEditing {
        TextField("Type a Name", text: $name) {
            myManagedObjectObserved = name
        }
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    } else {
        TextField("Type a Name", text: $name) {
            myManagedObjectObserved = name
        }
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

**Update:** more convenient variant (with same idea)

```
extension TextField {
    @ViewBuilder
    func editingStyle(if flag: Bool) -> some View {
        if flag {
            self.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        } else {
            self.textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var isEditing = false

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type a Name", text: $name) {
            myManagedObjectObserved = name
        }
        .editingStyle(if: isEditing)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Asperi. Your answer is exactly how I had the code structure set up prior (and I probably should have included that in my question for context), however I am attempting to streamline my code **and** animate the changes for the switch between isEditing = true and isEditing = false. Also if I read the Apple docs, they are both of type TextFieldStyle, so this is what is confusing for me.

Comment: @andrewbuilder, `TextFieldStyle` is a protocol - not a type. It is used as generics restriction in textFieldStyle modifier, so concrete type is required - single.

Comment: Ahhh... yep thank you understand now. Also your update with the `TextField` extension animates smoothly too, as it is not dropping one view and creating another with the change to `var isEditing`.

Comment: I keep reading about how protocols are not the same as interfaces in other languages (which is mainly the reason this problem happens), and I have yet to see 1 benefit that weights more than the drawback we get, like in this answer. Coming from languages like C#, Typescript and Java, I can't believe this answer is something the community deems acceptable in Swift language design.

Comment: I find this solution has limited usage, because changing TextFieldStyle removes focus (macOS at least).

Comment: @soundflix this is also true in iOS17. So this is really unusable.